# Date Picker Not working in yii2 Advanced

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to the Yii2 Advanced framework and am trying to insert a datepicker in an active form from a model.

I am using [2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget) widgets for date picker and updated my composer.json.

This is my code for Active Form

```
use dosamigos\datepicker\DatePicker;

<?= $form->field($model, 'user_date_birth')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
      // inline too, not bad
      'inline' => true,
      // modify template for custom rendering
      'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
      'clientOptions' => [
         'autoclose' => true,
         'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
      ]
]);?>
```

but it does not show the datepicker on click and no errors are displayed.

How can I update my code to display the datepicker?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the given piece of code, the problem must be located somewhere else. Maybe your model is corrupted, or something wrong with your attribute. Nevertheless, how should datepicker be shown on click if it's unfolded initially?

Comment: thanks for your reply.There was problem in one of my js which was conflicting it

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong in your code ... but i think there is a problem in jquery .. add it in your AppAsset.php